# Delete() views and template code

Tags: python, django

Template:

```
<form method="POST" action="/customer/delete/">
<div style="float: right; 
             margin: 0px; padding: 05px; ">
Name:<select  name="customer">
{% for customer in customer %}
<option value="{{ customer.name|escape }}" ></option><br />
{% endfor %}
</select>
<input type=submit value="delete">  
</div>
</form>
```

Views:

```
def delete(request, name):
       Customer.objects.get(name=name).delete()
       return HttpResponse('deleted')
```

Urls.py

```
(r'^customer/delete/', 'quote.excel.views.delete'),
```

This isnt working,plz correct the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Customer.objects.get(name = request.POST['name']).delete()
```

By the way, are you sure that the `action` variable in the template is indeed `'delete'`? If it isn't, the url called (and hence the method) will be different.

```
<form method="POST" action="/customer/{{ action }}/">
```

Comment: @amarghosh In my template drop down box is not fetching data from db.Where is the bug?

Comment: @daffodil It depends on the original view - you've posted the view for delete button's click handler.

Answer (score 1):

Your URLConf isn't catching any data to pass on to the variable `name`.  You need to either catch it as a part of the URL, or leave it to catch in a POSTed argument.

As part of the URL:

```
(r'^customer/(?P<name>[a-z]*)/delete/', 'quote.excel.views.delete')

def delete(request, name):
    if request.method == "POST": 
        # GET requests should NEVER delete anything, 
        # or the google bot will wreck your data.
        Customer.objects.get(name=name).delete()
```

As a post variable:

```
(r'^customer/delete/', 'quote.excel.views.delete')

def delete(request):  # No arguments passed in
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST['name']
        Customer.objects.get(name=name).delete()
```

Comment: I have problem with that url,which you have stated above  Page not found (404)
Request Method:  POST
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer/(?P%3Cname%3E[a-z]*)/delete/ .This is the error.

Comment: There was a missing parenthesis.  It's fixed now.

Comment: My self corrected it,but still it is the same.Thnx for your help.Plz see,this you will know where is the mistk http://dpaste.com/hold/167216/

Comment: delete view,it is stating this error delete() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)